# find duplicate values by some column and different in other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these table

```
article  type    date

apple    fruit   20180120
apple    fruit   20180119
banana   fruit   20180120
banana   fruit   20180120
```

How could I get:

```
apple fruit 20180120
apple fruit 20180119
```

I'm trying to find the registers that have article and type equals and date different.
Thanks and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `COUNT( DISTINCT .. ) OVER ( PARTITION BY .. )` analytic function to count the number of non-duplicate (i.e. `DISTINCT`) rows in each partition:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ce674/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( article, type, "date" ) AS
SELECT 'apple',  'fruit', DATE '2018-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'apple',  'fruit', DATE '2018-01-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 'fruit', DATE '2018-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 'fruit', DATE '2018-01-20' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT article,
       type,
       "date"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT "date" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY article, type ) AS ct
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  ct > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ce674/1/0)**:

```
| ARTICLE |  TYPE |                 date |
|---------|-------|----------------------|
|   apple | fruit | 2018-01-19T00:00:00Z |
|   apple | fruit | 2018-01-20T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Woo thanks! it works. These analytic function is used by these examples types?I did not know anything about these function

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you group records by what is your key (article, type) in this case.
and include group into output only if there is only one record (HAVING condition)

```
select article, type, min(date) as date
from your_table
group by article, type
having count(*) = 1
```

Second attempt:

```
select article, type, date
from your_table
group by article, type, date
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: This will only get one item from the article/type group - the OP's required output shows all the non-duplicate rows.

Comment: it would not, banana would have count(*) = 2.

Comment: My bad - I meant to say that it would return all rows that do not have a duplicate. So if there was a single `apricot`, `fruit`, `20180120` row then it would also get returned by this query even though it does not match the OP's requirements.